# Creating sets of specific extracted values from a .txt file (Python)

Tags: python, file, set

I have a .txt file that says "NAMES," "POINTS" and "SUMMARY" in capital letters, each followed by lines containing data. Each of these three groups is separated by an empty line:

```
NAMES
John Cena
Sam Smith
Selena Gomez

POINTS
sixteen
forty
thirty

SUMMARY
eighth place
sixth place
first place
```

My goal is to create three separate sets of names, points and summary.

I already created a set of names using the following code (which outputs a set of all names as intended):

```
names = set()

for line in open('handout_example.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        break
    names.add(line)

names.remove('NAMES')
print(names) #this outputs a set of all names
```

However, I am unsure on how to create a set of points and a set of summary given they're after an empty line and not at the start of the code unlike names.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:

```
names = set()
points = set()
summary = set()

next = 0

for line in open('handout_example.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        next += 1
        continue
    if next == 0:
       names.add(line)
    elif next == 1:
       points.add(line)
    elif next == 2:
       summary.add(line)

names.remove('NAMES')
points.remove('POINTS')
summary.remove('SUMMARY')

print(f'{names}\t{points}\t{summary}')
```

It simple and could be done better but this will work for you I guess.

EDIT: more "pretty" vesrion:

```
nps = dict({'names': set(), 'points': set(), 'summary': set()})
nps_n = ['names', 'points', 'summary']

next = 0

for line in open('handout_example.txt'):
   line = line.strip()

   if not line:
      next += 1
      continue
   
   nps[nps[next]].append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to detect if you see an empty line or the title line so you can then choose the appropriate type. For example:

```
data_types = {"NAMES":set(), "POINTS":set(), "SUMMARY":set()}

current_key = None
```

Then in your loop, check if the line matches one of the data types (and is not an empty line). If it does, set the current_key to that value and add to the set in the correct spot in the dictionary.

Comment: A dictionary is a natural approach here whenever you're dealing with adding data based on a certain condition (like matches a name or title). It reduced variable count and cleans up the code as well.